# why isnt god fixing everything?

Tags: creation

I have heard that knowledge is like a sword and depends on the wielder how he uses it, so my question is why not only create people who wants the welfare of everyone? Someone plz help what kind of a sport is this creation? I am just a curious person who understands simple answer not just bookish texts

Comment: If God will fix everything, what are you supposed to do?

Comment: Good karmas ,helping people to a greater extent, I could enjoy life and sports, laugh a little more and be really grateful to god@AmritenduMukhopadhyay

Comment: god is fixing everything, but it takes time, so be patient...lol

Answer (score 2):

Rather than asking why *He* is not fixing everything, ask why *you* are not fixing everything, as you are one of His worldly creations. The world is only as sorrowful as the beings that inhabit it.

There are several sources describing the procession of *yugas* or world ages. It degenerates from an Edenic golden age (Krita/Satya yuga), down through the Treta and Dvapara yugas, and finally to the Kali yuga (the age of gloom, strife, darkness). We currently live in the Kali yuga, and though it is indeed in need of fixing, it is not without its benefits. According to the [Vishnu Purana](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp157.htm#page_627):

> As my son plunged down into the water, and again rose up from it, the Munis heard him exclaim, **"Excellent, excellent, is the Kali age!"** Again he dived, and again rising, said in their hearing, "Well done, well done Śúdra; thou art happy!" Again he sank down, and as he once more emerged they heard him say, "Well done, well done, women; they are happy! who are more fortunate than they?" After this, my son finished his bathing, and the sages met him as he approached to welcome them. After he had given them seats, and they had proffered their respects, the son of Satyavatí said to them, "On what account have you come to me?" They replied, "We came to you to consult you on a subject on which we entertain some doubt; but that may be at present suspended: explain to us something else. We heard you say, 'Excellent is the Kali age! Well done, Śúdra! Well done, women!' Now we are desirous to know why this was said, why you called them repeatedly, happy. Tell us the meaning of it, if it be not a mystery. We will then propose to you the question that occupies our thoughts."
>
> Being thus addressed by the Munis, Vyása smiled, and said to them, "Hear, excellent sages, why I uttered the words 'Well done, well done.' **The fruit of penance, of continence, of silent prayer, and the like, practised in the Krita age for ten years, in the Treta for one year, in the Dwápara for a month, is obtained in the Kali age in a day and night: therefore did I exclaim, 'Excellent, excellent, is the Kali age!'** That reward which a man obtains in the Krita by abstract meditation, in the Treta by sacrifice, in the Dwápara by adoration, he receives in the Kali by merely reciting the name of Keśava. In the Kali age a man displays the most exalted virtue by very little exertion; therefore, pious sages, who know what virtue is, I was pleased with the Kali age.

TL;DR: in the Kali yuga, sin is not as harmful to one's karma, and merit is much more powerful than it is in one of the previous, more happy ages.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Yuga

Comment: I once heard a quote "Yesterday I was clever, so I wanted to change the world. Today I am wise, so I am changing myself".                              So my one question would be to you will be that why should I believe what is quoted by you from the scriptures or in general why should I believe the scriptures?@WalterC.Murrell

Comment: If you don't believe the scriptures are an authority, then why ask the question about God? Go do as thou wilt!

If, however, you believe the ancient texts have something to teach you, then give up sin! Recognize that your current experience is the presence of God. Connect with that source, and acknowledge that the traditions of the past are here to teach you things the elders knew that you do not know. They experienced that same connection to God that you now seek thousands of years ago.

They may teach you yet.

Comment: I want to believe in god but dont know whether the scriptures are really the authorities?What makes them the authority?Cant we question and suggest suggestion to the authorities?Why should I believe the scriptures Sir, that is my question. I want to know God.There are so many scriptures and religions,whom to believe?@WalterC.Murrell